# AutoIt Map Declaration Error

Tags: autoit

I get an error when I try to declare a map like this:

```
Global $g_fileId[]
```

It says: 
Global $g_fileId[]
Global $g_fileId[^ ERROR

Error Variable subscript badly formatted.

How do I format a map declaration in autoit correctly?

edit: I'm running version 3.4.1

Comment: Do you run your code with Beta? ALT+F5

Comment: Give 'Dim $m[]' a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare array in that way. You must declare the size of array:

```
Global $g_fileId[0]
```

Later you can increase the size with _ArrayInsert() .

Answer (score 0):

It's a map not a array ...

> Maps must be declared before use by defining their scope using the 'Global/Local/Static' keywords.
>   Local $mControls[]

From autoit help file ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Maps are ***still*** only supported in Beta releases of AutoIt3!

See: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/178187-maps-101-all-you-need-to-know-about-them/

If you are committed to using Maps, get the Beta [from here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/files/category/5-beta/).